# O que significa *(int *)

Tags: c

Estou lendo um código que possui coisas do tipo.

```
  *(int *)ptrArray = intN;
  *(float *)ptrArray= floatN;
```

Fica claro que estão sendo atribuidos tipos diferentes à um mesmo vetor do tipo `void*`. A questão é, qual o significado de `*(int *)` ou `*(float *)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digamos que eu tenha um ponteiro para um inteiro

```
int* iPtr;
```

Considerando que ele já aponte para um endereço válido da memória, se eu quiser alterar o valor do mesmo eu preciso primeiro derreferenciar o ponteiro

```
*iPtr = 100; //atribuo o valor 100
```

Então esse `*` é o que indica que estou derreferenciando este ponteiro e atribuindo o valor a memória para a qual ele aponta, caso eu não tivesse o `*` ali eu estaria tentando alterar o endereço para o qual este ponteiro aponta

Porém isso funciona pois o compilador conhece o tipo, quando se usa `void*` você possui um ponteiro genérico, como não se tem um tipo definido você não pode simplesmente derreferenciar este ponteiro, então você precisa primeiro fazer o cast dele para um outro tipo de ponteiro para então poder derreferenciar ele, considerando que temos uma variável `void* voidPtr`, no exemplo

```
*(int*)voidPtr = 100;
```

Primeiro o `(int*)` faz o cast de `void*` para `int*`, em seguida o primeiro `*` derreferencia o ponteiro para poder atribuir o valor

Comment: Agora tudo faz sentido! Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

As expressões devem ser lidas da seguinte forma:

1) O valor de `ptrArray`, que estou tratando como um ponteiro para `int`, recebe `intN` (que é um `int`)

1) O valor de `ptrArray`, que estou tratando como um ponteiro para `float`,  recebe `floatN` (que é um `float`)

Isso acontece porque você quer colocar um valor (e não um endereço) no lugar apontado por `ptrArray`, que é um ponteiro para uma sequência de dados de tipo indefinido (`void*`). Logo, precisamos da conversão forçada antes do nome da variável, ou o compilador apontará um erro.

O GCC 4.9.2 diria: `error: invalid use of void expression`

Comment: Isso eu entendo que que acontece, o que quero saber é o que a sintaxe significa. Principalmente por que o * antes do casting (int*).